# Get value of a variable from another session in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How to share variables' values in org-mode between different sessions?

Simple example: in session *one* I create `_gpg_tmpdir`

```
#+name: make_temporary_directories
#+begin_src bash :session *one*
_gpg_tmpdir="$( mktemp -d )"
#+end_src
```

and need to clean up it in session *two*:

```
#+name: clean_temporary_directories
#+begin_src bash :session *two*
rm -rf $_gpg_tmpdir
#+end_src
```

The example is for the demonstration purpose only.
The question is what is the less painfull way to share variables between different code sessions (perhaps with different code languages) in org-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the name of the codeblock to reference its output from a different codeblock using the "var" attribute. For more info you can check in the orgmode [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Environment-of-a-Code-Block.html#Environment-of-a-Code-Block).

The first block needs to output the value:

```
#+name: make_temporary_directories
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :session *one* :results output
variable=`ls`
echo $variable
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: make_temporary_directories
: 
: file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8
```

The second block can refer to that value using the name of the previous codeblock:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :session *two* :results output :var ls_result=make_temporary_directories
echo $ls_result
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example

bash-5.0$ file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8
#+end_example
```